# Probability : Two dice are thrown r times.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Two dice are thrown r times. Find the probability $p_r$ that each of the six combinations $(1,1),\ldots,(6,6)$ appears at least once.

My approach : As per my understanding will this be 1 - Pr(at least one of the pair does not occur in $r$ trials) ? 
So will this be $1 - (\Sigma_{i=1}^6\frac{(-1)^{(i-1)} * {^6}C_i*(36-i)^r}{36^r})$ ?

Comment: "At least one" is the complementary to "no one". The probability for "no double" is $(36-6)/36$ if we assume the dice are fair.

Comment: 1-Pr(no double) ensures at least one double but we need all the doubles to appear at least once.

Comment: Oh, ok... I see... Thank you for the point. Then we can try to change the question then for "some double never appear". We will have six different double and an OR statement of these six probabilities, so we will use the principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Maybe that it should read $p(r) = 1 - \frac{1}
{{36^{\,r} }}\sum\limits_{1\, \leqslant \,i\, \leqslant \,6} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,i - 1} \left( \begin{gathered}
  6 \\ 
  i \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( {36 - i} \right)^{\,r} } 
$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct; it's based on De Morgan's law and the expansion of the probability of a union (of 6 events, in your case). Note that the formula returns zero for r from 0 to 5 (check) and tends to one (rather slowly) as r increases.